# How to read a Config file?

Tags: python, config

I am trying to read a `config.ini` file that contains information on whether certain functions which are stored in a separate file need to be performed or not. The idea is that if the function is equal to `yes` in the config file, the function is then performed. Unfortunately I can't make this work, and I am not sure why.

My config file looks like this:

```
getStartLocation = yes
getEndLocation = yes
```

My main function looks like this:

```
def main():
    if getStartLocation == yes:
        start_location = getStartLocation(infile)
```

Comment: No offense, but how exactly how are you expecting this to work? How should `main` know what is `getStartLocation`? Where exactly are you *__reading__* the config.ini?

Comment: If `getStartLocation` has been set to `yes` (whatever that is), then calling it would be the same as calling `yes()` — which doesn't make much sense.